# Splint static code analysis segmentation fault

Tags: c, static-analysis, splint

Hey I'm trying to do some static analysis on a c cqde project I've written, but splint is giving me an error

```
$ splint -preproc ASL_ACAN.c
Splint 3.1.1 --- 28 Apr 2003
*** Segmentation Violation
*** Location (not trusted): Command Line
*** Last code point: llmain.c:659
*** Previous code point: llmain.c:588
*** Please report bug to splint-bug@splint.org
```

Not even sure where to start on this one, does anyone have any suggestions?  Basically any file in this project returns this error

Comment: Please report bug to splint-bug@splint.org

Comment: I'm pretty sure they haven't developed splint in the last 5 years...

Comment: "28 Apr 2003"?   I'd guess you should be looking elsewhere.